Does determinism rule out chance?
It is said that in a purely deterministic world, there would be no room for objective chance. Every event would then have a probability of either 1 or 0.
But isn’t chance fundamentally about X occurring for no reason/efficient cause instead of Y? For example, in some interpretations of quantum mechanics, a radioactive atom decays at a time t without an efficient cause. What this means is that the atom decays at time t instead of some other possible time without a cause. One can only give a probability of decay thus exemplifying the idea that this occurs by chance. If there is an efficient cause for the decay time, then it is now determined and thus the “chanciness” goes away.
But even if the universe was determined, the following question can still be asked: why those laws instead of other laws? Or why order instead of pure disorder?
If those questions have no answers to them, and a chance process goes hand in hand with processes that don’t have a deeper explanation, wouldn’t a deterministic universe also occur (or exist) by chance?

That is the definition of determinism. There is no chance, there is no decision, things just happen. I find that a completely unsatisfying view of the world and it's not worth wasting time on, but there is no way to disprove it.

@keshlam I think thats a good way to put it.  I find myself "defending" determinism a lot here only because a lot of people use poor reasoning to "disprove" it.  It's a really bad way to actually account for a lot of things as we experience them though. So I definitely agree it's not very satisfying (or practical) to think about the world that way.

If the universe with its laws is necessary, then its existence would not be explained by chance.

@user80226 metaphysical necessity = logically contingent

By definition, determinism rules out objective randomness within the universe. That the universe itself, with its deterministic laws, may exist 'by chance' (whatever that means) is a separate issue. And even if it does, that will be of little consequence to those bound by its deterministic laws.

@Conifold The question isn’t about whether chance can be ruled out within the universe, but whether it can be ruled out period under determinism. If there is no reason for a certain set of deterministic laws to play out instead of another set, then from an “existential” perspective, they are logically contingent and thus occur by “chance”

Don't forget that probabilities are subjectively evaluated depending on the information we have about a system. Shuffle a cards deck and return the top card: if the top card is the 7 of Spades, then the probability you'll draw this card is 100%, it's already decided. But you don't know that, so to you and the people you are playing with, the probability is 1/52, which is why you can all play a suspenseful game based on probabilities even though the order cards are going to come out is already fixed. It's because you don't have access to complete information that "chance" is involved.

That is not an advisable question to ask. One can keep asking for reasons and then for reasons to reasons indefinitely, so everything is 'by chance' under any doctrine in your vacuous sense.

@Conifold “That is not an advisable question to ask”, as spoken by millions of people in history who turned out to be wrong every single time. But anyhow, that is the point of the question. If the source of everything has no reason, then does it not occur by chance if something occurring for no reason is fundamentally tied to the concept of it? This explains the tons of people using (potentially) chancy processes in QM to try to disprove the PSR. They just haven’t taken it a step further with respect to scientific laws. There is no vacuousness here.

Are you sure? History is full of less than profound questions, and sometimes a cigar is only a cigar. "Does it not occur by chance if something occurring for no reason is fundamentally tied to the concept of it" is unintelligible. And people do discuss randomness of scientific laws in fine-tuning debates, for example, they just do not lump it together with determinism and various other uses of "chance". For the same reason they do not trade in unqualified generalities when they want to express something cogent.

@Conifold it’s actually pretty easy to understand. If there is no reason for the radioactive atom to decay at time t instead of t + 1, we say it occurs by chance. If there is no reason for the laws to be one way rather than another, it is not remarkably dissimilar to then say the laws are there by chance, atleast in an existential sense.

A fair coin has two states, a die has six states. These are deterministic statements and the calculation of Probabilities for a fair toss is based on these deterministic statements even if I can't determine the outcome of the next toss.

@keshlam Nature doesn't ask for your permission. And I disagree, it is not a waste of time. On the contrary, understanding and accepting determinism leads to a more humane world. If there is no free will and we can not keep people responsible for their deeds then our criminal justice system is fundamentally flawed and unnecessarily cruel. Moreover it should make us think twice before we heap praise on people born with good genes or lots of money. A deeper understanding of our universe can make us more compassionate and gracious. Accomplishing this is not a waste of time.

@Philomath: the problem may be that I don't find determinism at all plausible, and have trouble understanding those who do. So, yes, if discussion helps people understand why it is not a productive idea, great.

@Philomath: I intended to write that I did not find it a path worth going down. I accidentally left out a few words. Apologies to all.

Determinism is mostly concerned with how this universe works in the present and the recent past. It is less concerned with the origin of the universe. As such, a Big bang could be exceptional in not being deterministic, without changing anything else about determinism.
Of course philosophy thinks about whether and when and how and why and why so this universe came into existence, but science is unlikely to find answers beyond what is still observable today, and so the actual events and causes may remain unknown and unknowable forever (excluding divine revelation or similar supernatural events). Philosophy cannot break that barrier any more than science, because philosophy follows science.
So the issue is less concerning for determinism, but more concerning for pre determinism: that something planned all that happens and set the universe in motion in a way to make things happen exactly as planned. But that's not determinism, and the question does not ask about that.

I think reality is 100% deterministic.  Meaning... at the fundamental scale... there is only action and reaction... there is no "maybe this, maybe that".
However... the "environment" at the fundamental scale is permeated with information travelling every-which-way, and from many many sources...
... which, if the case, results in reality at our scale (emergent)... being impossible to predict, because we can never have awareness of all information.
I don't think "determinism" has to rule out chance, and choice, and other such goodies (like awareness and free will) at our scale.  We are at a scale that includes transience... beginnings, endings, cycles, periods of duration.  Those are not necessarily characteristics/properties that exist at all scales.
So I vote for (irony)... determinism, with a dash of chance existing because of the difference of scale at which the two phenomenon exist.
We can look at the stars, and choose a direction based on their arrangements...sub-atomic interactions have no such information to consider.

There was no poll called where a vote is possible. Truth is not a matter of opinions.

Where humanity has no answer that has been agreed upon, one can only state what one expects is the case, or may be the case, and not what is the case.  I would suggest anyone suggesting any potential answer is really just casting a customized vote.  At this point in our collective understanding.  Wouldn't you agree if painted that way?
Or are you aware of an answer that is not "just" a (perhaps somewhat) reasoned "vote," when boiled down?

Or perhaps I should ask... "What is the truth?"... if not currently a matter of opinions?

In a purely deterministic world nothing happens by chance (or by choice), the probability of every event is 1.
Chance means that there is no reason for X happening instead of Y, because a chance is not a choice. Only choices are made for reasons. Chance does have an efficient cause that makes it happen, but it does not have a sufficient cause to determine the outcome with absolute precision.
Radioactive decay is efficiently caused by the addition of an extra particle in the nucleus. But the time of the decay is not sufficiently caused, only the probability distribution of the decay times is known.
The laws of physics are only human-written descriptions of how the world works. In the context of a deterministic world a more important question is: "Why these events occur instead of some other events?"
Determinism does not answer that question. A deterministic world cannot evolve from a singularity, as there are no probabilistic events bringing any variation. The entropy and the Kolmogorov complexity of a deterministic system remain constant. Divine creation is also out of the question, as that would require a being with free will.

“Chance means that there is no reason for X happening instead of Y, because a chance is not a choice.” Yes, exactly. So in a deterministic universe, what reason is there to give for why a certain set of laws exist instead of another set of laws? If you say there’s no reason, then how do those laws not ultimately exist “by chance”?

Those laws exist by choice. People have written them. In a deterministic universe there are no people or laws.
